# move_group.setWorkspace() doesn't work?

Tags: moveit, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I am working on a project where I have to build lego structures collaberative with a human. Now I am new to moveit and have the cartesian path planning working in gazebo (sinusoidals, pick and place movement).

I was trying to use the move_group.setWorspace() function and for some reason it just doesn't give this information to the planning_scene_interface. When I execute a trajectory outside of it's workspace it will just go there for no reason. Also i wanted to implement anti-collision using octomapping however I don't think it will be a good idea to start on that if i can't control the size of my workspace properly.

PS: I also have changed the workspace settings in the moveit.rviz file from the ur5, I can see the workspace getting these dimensions in rviz however the ur5 will still go there.

Kind regards,
Edwin van Emmerik
CODE:

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "trajectory_tester");
ros::NodeHandle node_handle;
ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
spinner.start();
// Construct planning scene for the move_group
const std::string PLANNING_GROUP = "manipulator";
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface move_group(PLANNING_GROUP);
move_group.setWorkspace(-0.2, -0.2, 0.05, 1, 1, 1); // set workspace size for move_group
robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader("robot_description");
robot_model::RobotModelPtr robot_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();
// Make sure that the robot model gets loaded
if (robot_model != 0)
{
ROS_INFO("Robot model loaded");
}
else
{
ROS_INFO("Could not load robot model");
}

```
// Get the planning frames
ROS_INFO("Reference frame: %s", move_group.getPlanningFrame().c_str());
ROS_INFO("Reference frame: %s", move_group.getEndEffectorLink().c_str());
move_group.setPlannerId("PRMstarkConfigDefault"); //default planner is set to RTTCONNECT in ompl_planning_.yaml
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan my_plan;
/*
int chosenone;
std::cout << "You can choose between pick and place(1) and sinusoidal movements(2)" << std::endl;
std::cin >> chosenone;
std::cout << std::endl;
*/
// Construct target_pose object of type geometry_msgs
// Construct waypoints vector of type geometry_msgs::Pose
std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> waypoints;
geometry_msgs::Pose start_pose = move_group.getCurrentPose().pose;
geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose = start_pose;

        // Keep initiazlize state and also keep the UR5 facing downwards for default
        target_pose.position.x = 0.6;
        target_pose.position.y = 0.05;
        target_pose.position.z = 0.1;
        target_pose.orientation.w = 0.707;
        target_pose.orientation.x = 0;
        target_pose.orientation.y = 0.707;
        target_pose.orientation.z = 0;
        move_group.setPoseTarget(target_pose);
        move_group.plan(my_plan);
        move_group.move();
        

        int number_of_waypoints = 7;
        double x[number_of_waypoints];
        x[0] = 0.5;
        x[1] = 0.0;
        x[2] = 0.0;
        x[3] = 0.0;
        x[4] = 0.5;
        x[5] = 0.5;
        x[6] = 0.5;
        double y[number_of_waypoints];
        y[0] = 0.0;
        y[1] = 0.5;
        y[2] = 0.5;
        y[3] = 0.5;
        y[4] = 0.0;
        y[5] = 0.0;
        y[6] = 0.0;
        double z[number_of_waypoints];
        z[0] = 0.4;
        z[1] = 0.4;
        z[2] = 0.1;
        z[3] = 0.4;
        z[4] = 0.4;
        z[5] = 0.1;
        z[6] = 0.4;
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_waypoints; i++)
        {
            target_pose.position.x = x[i];
            target_pose.position.y = y[i];
            target_pose.position.z = z[i];
            waypoints.push_back(target_pose);
        }
```

/*    NOTE THAT THIS IS COMMENTED
// Creating the sine data in x and y coordinates
double amplitude = 0.1;
double w = 30.0;
double step = 0.005;
double upperLimit_x = 0.2;
double lowerLimit_x = -0.2;
double offset = 0.20;
int size = round( (upperLimit_x - lowerLimit_x)/step) + 1;
double x[size];
double y[size];
x[0] = lowerLimit_x;

```
        for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            x[i] = x[i-1] + step;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            y[i] = amplitude*sin((x[i]+offset)*w)+0.4;
            std::cout << y[i] << "  ";
        }
        // Inserting the sine data to waypoints
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            target_pose.position.x = x[i];
            target_pose.position.y = y[i];
            waypoints.push_back(target_pose);
        }
        // The same sine data but backwards
        for(int i = size-2; i != -1; i--) {
            target_pose.position.x = x[i];
            target_pose.position.y = -y[i]+0.8; // and inverted
            waypoints.push_back(target_pose);

        }
        // Creating sine data in x and z coordinates TODO
```

*/
// After whatever case is chosen return to its starting position
waypoints.push_back(start_pose);
moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
double fraction = move_group.computeCartesianPath(waypoints, 0.001, 0.0, trajectory);
ROS_INFO("Visualizing plan (cartesian path) (%.2f%% acheived)", fraction * 100.0);

```
// Adding time parametrization to the trajectory
robot_trajectory::RobotTrajectory rt(move_group.getCurrentState()->getRobotModel(), "manipulator");
rt.setRobotTrajectoryMsg(*move_group.getCurrentState(), trajectory);
trajectory_processing::IterativeParabolicTimeParameterization iptp;
bool success = iptp.computeTimeStamps(rt);
ROS_INFO("Computed time stamp %s",success?"SUCCEDED":"FAILED");
rt.getRobotTrajectoryMsg(trajectory);

std::cout << move_group.getPathConstraints() << std::endl; // NO CONSTRAINTS
sleep(2);
my_plan.trajectory_ = trajectory;
if (fraction == 1.0) {
    sleep(2);
    move_group.execute(my_plan);

}
else
{
    ROS_WARN("Could not compute the cartesian path :( ");
    std::cout << fraction << std::endl;
}
// Debug waypoints
/*
for(int k = 0; k < waypoints.size(); k++)
{
        std::cout << waypoints[k] << std::endl;
}
*/
waypoints.clear();
ros::shutdown();  
return 0;
```

}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273485/move_group.setworkspace()-doesn%27t-work?/) by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2017-10-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

the "workspace" parameter currently does not affect revolute joints!
The parameter was originally introduced to restrict the movement of mobile robots or drones to stay within some volume, modeled via Planar or Floating joints.

If you want to have the framework avoid regions in space please add collision objects for them.
If you want the arm to stay within some bounded volume, you can model this as "wall" collision objects.

P.S. The project sounds awesome! I'm somewhat jealous :-)

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) on 2017-10-20**:
Thanks for your answer. I do think it is a little weird, I have read most off the questions that were similar to this one and the reason I did ask it is because I thought they would have resolved it by now.

Do you mean with a wall just to add objects around the robot to use that as workspace?

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-10-21**:\

> they would have resolved it by now.

You are part of "they". Write a patch and I'm happy to review and merge it :-)

> mean with a wall just to add objects

That's how people worked around this in the past, yes...

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-10-21**:
It's probably also the easiest way upstream to add such collision objects when a workspace is configured...

**Comment by [EdwinvanEmmerik](https://answers.ros.org/users/32311/edwinvanemmerik/) on 2017-10-21**:
Yea I added 5 walls to my workspace and it is working now! Sounds really cool that everybody can help on improving moveit! I think it is quiet complicated and that is probably the reason why it is not implemented yet. Is there any documentation on writing patches? Just for self-interest!

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-10-22**:
Great!
If you want to contribute to MoveIt, have a look at http://moveit.ros.og and read through the "Contribute" section in the top panel.